# PHP: Select statement in foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I selected data from database which is mainly getting the username with the name match in `Where CONCAT_WS()` and i got an error in selecting for the second value.

```
foreach($names as $name){
if($name != ""){
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, "select CONCAT_WS('', fname, ' ', mname, ' ', lname) as name, username from user where CONCAT_WS('', fname, ' ', mname, ' ', lname) = '$name'");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
  $username = $row['username'];
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into message_send(username, receiver, message) values('$u','$username','$msg')");  
}     
}
```

after the first value was inserted successfully the second value got an error in which it does not insert the username. The output of this error is

```
Username | Receiver | Message
myuser   | user2    | this is a message
myuser   |          | this is a message
```

Answer (score 0):

For best results call `mysqli_close($query)` after your `mysql_fetch_array()` and `mysqli_close($sql)` right after your `insert` query. Those calls dismiss the resultsets and reset the connection so you can use it again.

You probably also should check each of your `mysqli_query()` operations for errors.

Comment: mysqli_query don't have errors. i think it's in mysqli_fetch_array.